# An old-fashioned synonym for "arrogant" and "thinking too high of oneself"

Tags: idioms, adjectives

I can't remember this idiom which I once heard and means "arrogant".  As I haven't heard it for a long time, say some 30 years, I presume it is outdated. It's a two-word idiom and sounds somewhat funny.   Context: I was at a cocktail with an English friend and we had just talked to a sophisticated lady who put on airs. My friend turned to me and said "humm, ..."idiom".

ps. I've gone through a few [lists](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/arrogant) of [synonyms](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/arrogant) for "arrogant" but couldn't find it.

Comment: Maybe 'stuck-up':  conceited, arrogant, or snobbish!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe *highfalutin*? It's only one word but sounds like two.

> adj. Informal
>   Pompous or pretentious: "highfalutin reasons for denying direct federal assistance to the unemployed" (Arthur M. Schlesinger, Jr.)
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition. S.v. "highfalutin." Retrieved November 2 2014 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/highfalutin

Also *hoity-toity* - see the definition here http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hoity-toity.

Comment: "hoity-toity"  That's exactly the idiom. Funny word. Have you heard people using it lately?

Comment: I use it - I use it more than 'highfalutin' (that sounds American to me - think Doris Day in a Western movie) but 'hoity-toity' I consider to be more British. Not sure I'd use it to mean arrogant, more like snooty and akin to 'fancy-dancy' and probably only used to describe a woman, not a man. I'm not sure how much use it gets in the UK these days, probably only older folks.

Comment: @Centaurus Forgot to put your name in my comment so you'd get an alert.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but I wanted to jump, was looking for the meaning of an old expression and saw your question.  The old idioms and expressions are fun to explore.

Hoity-Toity is a snob or show off, pretentious and believes they are better than the rest of us but not specific to arrogance, often new money, an air but not arrogant. This modern crude expression captures Hoity Toity, for meaning not blog:)

"He thinks his sh__ doesn't stink"

Don't have an idiom for arrogant, blowhard comes to mind. But I do have an occasion to throw out "... He is a legend in his own mind".  Sounds sexist but I have only had occasion when describing a dude.

Comment: Do you agree that it doesn't get much use these days ?

Comment: @Centaurus All those get used plenty.

Answer (score 1):

Also somewhat out-of-fashion is

**la-di-da** (adj.)

> **Variants** *or less commonly* la-de-da or lah-de-dah or lah-dee-dah or
> lah-di-dah
>
> Informal Affectedly or pretentiously elegant or refined in manners or
> tastes
>
> *...they soon became civilized. Two years later Fabyan saw them in Westminster Palace, dressed like **la-di-da** English courtiers.*
> —Samuel  Eliot Morison
>
> *Iris was a freshman at Climping Academy, the Santa Teresa private school located in Horton Ravine, which was so **la-di-da**, it totally
> freaked her out.*
> —Sue Grafton
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/la-di-da)

> Speech or behaviour that appears or strives to appear very refined or
> upper-class; affectation, pomposity, ‘poshness’. Also (and earliest)
> in **to do the la-di-da**: to behave in an extremely refined manner.
>
> **2002** I prefer to sup my bitter in a cosy snug where the barmaid calls
> me ‘luv’ without any **la-de-da-de-da**.
> *Daily Telegraph* (Nexis) 6 July
> [OED]

Also

**uppity** (adj.)

> 1. **somewhat old-fashioned** : putting on or marked by airs of superiority : arrogant, presumptuous
>
> *Uppity technicians*
>
> *A small uppity country*
>
> The truth is I am tired every afternoon and there's nothing to be done
> about it. It's the nature of the disease. A lot of people decide I am
> bored or indifferent or *uppity* but at a certain hour of the day my
> motor cuts off automatically.
> —Flannery O'Connor
>
> 2. **Somewhat old-fashioned, disparaging + sometimes offensive; see usage paragraph below**
>
> Aspiring to a rank or position higher than one deserves or is entitled
> to
>
> *In a seller's market for labor, it seems, there is a danger that the help will get uppity.*
> —Michael Lind
>
> **Usage of *Uppity***
> The adjective *uppity* is an informal, somewhat old-fashioned word.
> When used to mean "arrogant" or "presumptuous," it is no more
> offensive than either of these synonyms. In its meaning of "aspiring
> to a rank or position higher than one deserves or is entitled to" it
> is decidedly disparaging, the implication of the word being that the
> one described does not deserve or is not entitled to rise in standing.
> Beyond this denotation, however, *uppity* has a long history of being
> applied to members of racial minorities and especially to Black
> people. Its association with such uses, and the bigotry they
> represent, means that when it is used to describe a member of a racial
> minority it is likely to be considered especially offensive.
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uppity)